# Filtering ‘Featured’ posts from a batch of category IDs

Tags: wp-query, categories

My website has a group of main categories with their respective child categories. I am developing custom featured sections but needed help developing a WP_Query condition.

Is there a way to filter out posts filed to a 'Featured' category that also belong a certain category and it's children?

Example. My travel category (ID=1) has sub-categories like Hotels (ID=2), Tickets (ID=3), and Reviews (ID=4). I also have a Featured category (ID=8).

How do I filter posts filed to Featured but also belong to anyone of the above Travel category and/or sub-categories?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example code below, if you are using WordPress default post. For custom post type the query will be different.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'parent_category_slug+featured_category_slug', // change the category slug as your own
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()):

    while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

<?php
    endwhile; // main loop
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif; // have posts

?>
```

Comment: Would using the ID for the top category alone catch all posts filed in the sub-categories? For instance, if I checkmarked Hotels (sub category) but not the actual Travel category at the time of posting.

Comment: Yes. It does. Please check it, it should work for what are you looking for.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work as expected. It only pulls from either or, and does not filter as I wanted it to.

Comment: Sorry, I was missed your point. I edited the code, try it. It will pull posts from which is belongs to featured category and also the parent category or it's child category